# Password generator switch to using ascii string

Tags: python, passwords

Making a random password generator, and want to use the ascii strings, but do not know how to change from what I have so far to use the strings instead. This is what I have so far:

```
import random
import string

def UltimatePasswordGenerator():
    print('====================================================')
    print('==== WELCOME TO THE ULTIMATE PASSWORD GENERATOR ====')
    print('====================================================')
    try:
        length = int(input("Please enter the length of the password you want to create:\nNote: The minimum length is 8 characters And enter Only Numbers\n"))
        while length < 8:
            print("The minimum password length is 8 characters, please enter a valid number ")
            length = int(input("Enter the length of the password you want to create:\n"))
        password_uppercase = input("Answer only with yes or no.\nDo you want upper case? \n")
        while password_uppercase != "yes" and password_uppercase != "YES" and password_uppercase != "no" and password_uppercase != "NO":
            password_uppercase = input("Answer only with yes or no.\nDo you want upper case? \n")
        password_lowercase = input("Answer only with yes or no.\nDo you want lower case?\n")
        while password_lowercase != "yes" and password_lowercase != "YES" and password_lowercase != "no" and password_lowercase != "NO":
            password_lowercase = input("Answer only with yes or no.\nDo you want lower case?\n")
        password_numbers = input("Answer only with yes or no.\nDo you want numbers?\n")
        while password_numbers != "yes" and password_numbers != "YES" and password_numbers != "no" and password_numbers != "NO":
            password_numbers = input("Answer only with yes or no.\nDo you want numbers?\n")
        password_special = input("Answer only with yes or no.\nDo you want Special symbols?\n")
        while password_special != "yes" and password_special != "YES" and password_special != "no" and password_special != "NO":
            password_special = input("Answer only with yes or no.\nDo you want Special symbols?\n")
    except ValueError:
        print("Enter Only Number above 8")
    except:
        print("Sorry you got an error! Please enter a VALID value")
    else:
        alphabets = []   # keep a list of alphabet groups 
        if password_numbers in ("yes", "YES"):
            alphabets.append("0123456789")  # include group
        if password_uppercase in ("yes", "YES"):
            alphabets.append("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
        if password_lowercase in ("yes", "YES"):
            alphabets.append("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
        if password_special in ("yes", "YES"):
            alphabets.append("!#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~")
        password_chars = []  # construct the password as a list
        while len(password_chars) < length:  # keep choosing until length requirement is met
            for alphabet in alphabets:  # for each group
                password_chars.append(random.choice(alphabet)) # choose a character from the group
                if len(password_chars) > length:
                    break
        random.shuffle(password_chars) # shuffle to lose the order of groups from the generated list
        return "".join(password_chars)

print(UltimatePasswordGenerator())
```

Instead of using alphabets id like to use:
string.ascii_letters¶
string.ascii_lowercase¶
and so forth

Comment: What is the issue of your code?

Comment: Should be as simple as replacing `"abcdef..."` with `string.ascii_lowercase`, if that's what you're asking

Comment: Thank you August, I can't believe it was that simple haha.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
import string

def UltimatePasswordGenerator():
    print('====================================================')
    print('==== WELCOME TO THE ULTIMATE PASSWORD GENERATOR ====')
    print('====================================================')
    try:
        length = int(input("Please enter the length of the password you want to create:\nNote: The minimum length is 8 characters And enter Only Numbers\n"))
        while length < 8:
            print("The minimum password length is 8 characters, please enter a valid number ")
            length = int(input("Enter the length of the password you want to create:\n"))
        password_uppercase = input("Answer only with yes or no.\nDo you want upper case? \n")
        while password_uppercase != "yes" and password_uppercase != "YES" and password_uppercase != "no" and password_uppercase != "NO":
            password_uppercase = input("Answer only with yes or no.\nDo you want upper case? \n")
        password_lowercase = input("Answer only with yes or no.\nDo you want lower case?\n")
        while password_lowercase != "yes" and password_lowercase != "YES" and password_lowercase != "no" and password_lowercase != "NO":
            password_lowercase = input("Answer only with yes or no.\nDo you want lower case?\n")
        password_numbers = input("Answer only with yes or no.\nDo you want numbers?\n")
        while password_numbers != "yes" and password_numbers != "YES" and password_numbers != "no" and password_numbers != "NO":
            password_numbers = input("Answer only with yes or no.\nDo you want numbers?\n")
        password_special = input("Answer only with yes or no.\nDo you want Special symbols?\n")
        while password_special != "yes" and password_special != "YES" and password_special != "no" and password_special != "NO":
            password_special = input("Answer only with yes or no.\nDo you want Special symbols?\n")
    except ValueError:
        print("Enter a Number above 8")
    except:
        print("Sorry you got an error! Please enter a VALID value")
    else:
        alphabets = []    
        if password_numbers in ("yes", "YES"):
            alphabets.append("string.digits") 
        if password_uppercase in ("yes", "YES"):
            alphabets.append("string.ascii_uppercase")
        if password_lowercase in ("yes", "YES"):
            alphabets.append("string.ascii_lowercase")
        if password_special in ("yes", "YES"):
            alphabets.append("string.punctuation")
        password_chars = []  # construct the password as a list
        while len(password_chars) < length:  
            for alphabet in alphabets:  
                password_chars.append(random.choice(alphabet)) 
                if len(password_chars) > length:
                    break
        random.shuffle(password_chars) 
        return "".join(password_chars)

print("Your new password is: " + UltimatePasswordGenerator())
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).